# "tcpdump" to capture the last packets

Tags: tcp, tcpdump, tcp-ip

I am monitoring a certain port, because my application uses that port, it seems that the connection drops at random times, I want to see what are the last packets passing through before the connection drops:
I used this line

```
 sudo tcpdump -XX -i eth0 port 3050 | tail  >> tcpamir.txt
```

but for it to work I have to start another terminal and issue

```
sudo killall tcpdump
```

is there a better approach?
EDIT1: it is important to capture only the last packets since I don't want the file to balloon, since there is enough traffic to fill the disk space quickly .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I think I've found a [solution](https://superuser.com/questions/297521/how-to-capture-last-n-seconds-of-packets-using-tcpdump):

```
sudo tcpdump -XX -i eth0 -w tcpamir-%s.txt -G 10 port 3050
```

This rotates your output file every 10 seconds to a new file called `tcpamir-<unixtimestamp>.txt`

You can also modify the output file, so it overwrites itself every day, if you are worried about the pending file size. For more information read `man 3 strftime`.

I think of something like

```
sudo tcpdump -XX -i eth0 -w tcpamir-%R.txt -G 86400
```

Where `%R` gives the time in 24-hour notation (12:40 e.g.).

Read relevant output files with

```
sudo tcpdump -r tcpamir-<unixtimestamp>.txt
```

Second solution:

Split it into more commands and save it as a script/function:

```
sudo tcpdump -XX -i eth0 port 3050 >> tcptmp.txt
sudo tail -n100 tcptmp.txt >> tcpamir.txt
sudo rm tcptmp.txt
```

Comment: do you think it is possible to just make it rotate on itself ? as in remove the -%R from the file ? would it just rewrite ?

Comment: I tried, but it somehow stays at 0. If you go with the above cmd, it should work, but also log for 24 hours and overwrite/delete all log info at the 24h mark.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to write all traffic captured you only have to add -w to the line removing **'| tail >>  tcpamir.txt'**

```
# tcpdump -XX -i eth0 port 3050 -w tcpamir.cap
```

If you would analize the capture in wireshark the extension must be .cap 
When you ensure that the capture is done, you could kill this with **ctrl + c**

**NOTE: -w [filename.cap] to write the capture into a file**

Comment: but this way,the file will be way to big as it might be 24h before the error happens, and storage is limited

Comment: So you are worried about the total size & not the way to write the output without killing the PID with an other terminal?

Comment: size is the reason i used tail in such a way, but i dont like the way i did it. i feel that there must be a better way.

Comment: what do you say about my suggestion?